# How to display DateTime with just the date component

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

```
<asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval('SomeDate') %> />
```

This displays showing the date and time. However I just want to display the date.

I'm aware that in the code behind you can write SomeDate.ToString("dd MM yyyy");

However I want a way of doing this by changing the code in the tag instead.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <%# Eval("SomeDate","0:dd-MMM-yyyy") %> or of course any date format you like.

Comment: It just printed out 0:dd-MMM-yyyy

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your requirement, but in you code behind you can also do

```
string formattedDate = SomeDate.ToShortDateString();
```

and in your tag, just display the formatted date

```
<asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval('formattedDate') %> />
```