# How do I convert a DateTime object to a string with just the date using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Seemingly simple. I need to convert a DateTime object to a string without the time stamp.

This gives me the date and time. And I can't figure out how to just get the date.

```
        startDate = Convert.ToString(beginningDate);
```

This outputs: 10/1/2011 12:00:00 AM

I need it to be: 10/1/2011 as a string

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display DateTime with just the date component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111606/how-to-display-datetime-with-just-the-date-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
string startdate = beginningDate.ToShortDateString ();
```

For MSDN reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Check out [`.ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

```
string startDate = beginningDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Also check out the [`.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method on `DateTime` that takes a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx). For example:

```
string startDate = beginningDate.ToString("d");
```

**Example:** http://ideone.com/tpyZy

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this;

DateTime dt = beginningDate;
  StringBuilder sbDate = Convert.toString(dt.year);//and further for others month and days